`yum clean all` differs regarding handling disabled repositories
I'm porting some old build scripts from CentOS 7 to Rocky 8. I've noticed that the following command cleans all repository caches on Rocky 8, as opposed to just the caches of the one enabled repository:
yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=my-local-repo clean all

My build scripts execute this command many, many times to refresh the locally-stored repository after subsequent RPMs are built and installed into that repository. On Rocky 8 this means hitting network after each execution, as the next yum-builddep will try to re-download all standard repositories—making the build script quite a bit slower.
I have found this old bug entry: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1357083, which states the CentOS 7 behavior is actually the intended one, so I assume something must have changed between CentOS 7 and Rocky 8.
What is now the intended way to remove cache and trigger refetching indexes for exactly one repository?
